# Pybind11: is make_tuple() owns wrapped pointers?

Tags: pybind11

Suppose I have a function like this, which I'm wrapping in Pybind11:

```
void func(){
  SomeCppType* var1 = new SomeCppType();
  SomeCppType* var2 = new SomeCppType();
  return py::make_tuple(var1,var2)
}
```

What will happen with ownership of pointers? Is it posisble to tell pybind11::tuple to own the pointers and call delete on them? What is the correct way of writing this?

Comment: I guess it will return a python tuple which contains two pointers. The two pointers can be called if you define some functions for Python to call.

Answer (score 0):

`py::make_tuple` is a templated function so you can do

`return py::make_tuple<py::return_value_policy::take_ownership>(var1,var2);`
with any return policy.